# Should I validate access permissions each request?

Tags: security, validation, web-applications, user-permissions

I've always wondered whether it's better to check the database for account access permissions every single request, or cache (say, an ACL) in the session state.

My current case isn't particularly mission-critical, but I feel it would be annoying to have to logout and log back in to refresh cached credentials.  I've also considered using a temporary data store, with a TTL.  Seems like it might be the best of both.

Comment: Give the permissions table a clustered index on user id and fetching a user's permissions list should put little or no load on the server, making caching pointless.

Comment: Hmm... I don't have a centralized permissions table--that info is in multiple m:n tables.  Would you recommend centralizing?

Comment: How many tables would have to be checked on a particular request? How many rows of each table?

It would be wise to centralize if you have to check more than a couple of tables, because you turn N clustered index scans (on user id) into just one which returns more rows.

Comment: Right now it's only two or three tables, with a few hundred rows in each, but I expect it to grow quite a bit, and wanted to avoid unnecessary database queries as much as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security wise, it is better to check the DB every time for permissions.  The security vulnerability comes in that if the user's permission are *reduced* after the session is created, they could potentially still be achieving a higher level of access than they should.

There are a few things you can do to stay secure without performing a full query, provided you're early enough in the development cycle.  If you have [role-based access control (RBAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control), you can store a fast lookup table that contains a user's role.  If the user's role changes during the session, you mark the permissions "dirty" in the lookup table, causing a querying of the DB for the new role.  As long as the user's role stays the same, there's no need to query the DB.  The lookup table then, is basically just a flag that you can set on the backend if the user's role changes.  This same technique can be used even with individual access controls, provided the granularity is not too fine.  If it is, it starts to become a bloat on your server.  We use this technique at work to speed up transactions.

If you are late in the development cycle or if you value simplicity more than performance (simple is usually more secure), then I would query the DB every time unless the load gets too heavy for the DB.